# How can I add a simple generic type annotation in UML?

Tags: uml

1. In a class diagram, the value of one of the attributes of a class is a (typed) tuple.  In Python, I would annotate it as `Tuple[A,B]`. What is a proper UML type annotation?
2. In a class diagram, the value of one of the attributes of a class is essentially an associative array.  In Python, I would annotate this as `Sequence[Tuple[A,B]]`. What is a proper UML type annotation?
3. In a class diagram, the value of one of the attributes of a class is a (typed) dictionary.  In Python, I would annotate this as `Dict[A,B]`. What is a proper UML type annotation?

To be clear: I do not wish to add class boxes for `Tuple`, `Sequence`, or `Dict` to the diagram.

Comment: Please ask a single question at a time. Only #3 is duplicate. So ask 2 new questions.

Comment: If you ask a new question, clarify with 2 if you mean an associative array (i.e. a dictionary) or an array of tuples rerepesenting an association.